# Ajax post doesnt post "&" letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I successfully posy via ajax. However, I realized that it doesnt post "&". It also doesnt give any error. Here is my script

**Html**

```
<textarea id="aciklamatext">West & Union</textarea>
```

**Ajax post**

```
var aciklama = $('#aciklamatext').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",datatype:"json",  async: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    url: "/aciklama.php",        
    data: "aciklama=" + aciklama,
    success: function(html){
    }
});
```

**aciklama.php**

```
$aciklama = $_POST["aciklama"];
echo $aciklama;
```

### **Output**

West

Comment: First of all, the character should be escaped as `&amp;` in your HTML source code.

Comment: It is. This is the first entry post when user inputs data.

Comment: It isn't in your question. `West & Union` is there, unescaped.

Comment: I wrote there to tell that the value there will be posted via ajax post.

Comment: you need to send it in JSON becoz of your content-type the data is been Send as aciklama=Western&Union so its considering Union as different Variable

Comment: Isnt there any way to escape it, like we use \ in php ?

Comment: Hello you can try encodeURIComponent and  decodeURIComponent in your js.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to send data by ajax is to use JSON. Internal ajax converts the JSON data to a string and encodes all the special chars:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   datatype:"json",  
   url: "/aciklama.php",        
   data: {"aciklama": + $('#aciklamatext').val()},
   success: function(data){
   }
});
```

One comment: The use of async false is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/